# Responsive design for working website

Tags: google-chrome-extension, responsive-design, livereload

I'm beginner web-developer, front-end only. Sometimes i need to make existing working websites to be responsive. I use browser extension(Styler for Chrome), that show me window where i can insert my styles, which will be applied for a page. But it looks little difficult(need to write code in my text-editor, copy this to extension form, than again, again and again...). Is there a way, to integrate my local stylesheet, to existing website, make changes only in my editor and reload page automatically, like with local page? I've found something on LiveReload website - 
http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/86220-preview-css-changes-against-a-live-site-then-uplo, but I can't use their app, cause i'm on windows(LiveReload is still in beta on it). If anybody use similar, can you please explain how to get it to work? Thanks.

Comment: I think it's only possible via [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging): write an external utility (it'll be started by Chrome automatically) that checks the file modification date and communicates with your extension so that it can reapply the styles. As an easier alternative, you may consider using [Stylish extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) that has built-in CodeMirror editor with a couple of advanced editing hotkeys and syntax highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In process of expiriencing I found simple solution for this:

1. Need to install Chrome extension(CSS Inject).
2. Run web-server on your machine which will host your css file for injecting(CSS Inject works only with HTTP) and insert it to CSS Inject, in my situation it looks like - http:// adapt/css/style.css
3. Need livereload server. I'am using node.js and this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload for this.
4. Create file in your web-site root(for example server.js)
5. Paste this code in server.js:

   var livereload = require('livereload'),
   server = livereload.createServer();

   server.watch(__dirname + "/css");
   console.log('waiting for changes');
6. Go to your live website and activate CSS Inject.
7. run node ./server.js
8. That's it. You can now modify your styles localy and see changes on real website.

If anybody knows better solution(using API from this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload#api-options, specifically **overrideURL** option) or have better expirience with node.js and understang how to implemet it, please post your solution here, I will be grateful.